# How do you make a Peer-to-Peer network over the internet?

Tags: peer-to-peer

In short terms, I want to make a Peer-to-Peer network with my friend for file sharing and lan-gaming. How can this be done? We have virtual ethernet adapters from open vpn and we are aware these can be used for p2p. How do we configire them to do this? Every time I look up how, I get how to do it with a cable instead of over the internet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't believe that the term "Peer-to-Peer network" is appropriate for what you are trying to do - you really need to describe your usage case better.  If you are using OpenVPN, you could either be talking about a "bridged" (using TAP devices) network or a regular (using TUN) devices network and ensure routing is correct.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what they both are, but I believe what I need is TAP. I'm trying to make a network that is like a separate LAN network that has been bridged over the internet.

Comment: Again, it is difficult for someone advises unless you describe what you are trying to achieve.  TAP devices will make your devices all appear to be directly connected (ie the Internet and VPN) become a giant switch.  There are usage cases for this, but it is quite inefficient compared to having 2 networks with routing between them [ ie if you use a TUN device things will work faster, but if you do a traceroute the computers on the remote side are visible through a router, rather then with no router visible ]

Answer (score 0):

[LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) is (one of several) VPN software that designed towards the idea of bridging distant LANs together via the internet such that the remote network appears local. There is plenty of documentation available on how to set it up for use when wanting to play LAN-only games over the internet.

Comment: While I am fully aware of this. I don't want any restrictions. Hamachi limits me to only 5 people per network. If I had one without restrictions, that would make me happier.

Comment: @ZacharyTeska Technically, it lets you have as many as you can pay for. But let's say Hamachi isn't for you. [This page](http://alternativeto.net/software/hamachi/?license=free) lists tons of free alternatives. [Freelan](http://alternativeto.net/software/freelan/) looks promising.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to find an open-source software, but there I couldn't. I will try and use this.